# Unable to deploy the Docker Image of Laravel application on Heroku

Tags: laravel, docker, heroku, docker-container, docker-image

I started to learn the Docker. I am a complete beginner to Docker. Now, what I am doing is trying to deploy a Docker image of Laravel application onto the Heroku. I have installed a Laravel project. My Laravel project has only one page, a welcome page showing a message. That's it. I am just trying to test Docker. I have created a Docker image for my Laravel project and successfully run it on my laptop as follow.

I created a Dockerfile in the project root folder with the following content.

```
FROM php:7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

Then I built the image like this

```
docker build -t waiyanhein/laravel c:/xampp/htdocs/docker_laravel
```

Then I run it locally by running the following command.

```
docker run –p 8181:8181 waiyanhein/laravel
```

Everything was working. Then I tried to deploy the image to Heroku. I followed this link, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime. As in the link, I logged into heroku.

```
heroku container:login
```

Login succeeded. Then I create the app running this command.

```
heroku create dockerlaravelwai
```

The command was successful and this is the result.
[image]

Then I pushed it as a next step as in the link mention by running the following command.

```
heroku container:push web
```

when I run the above command, I got the following error.

```
 »   Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 »   See more help with --help
```

What went wrong? How can I easily deploy the Laravel Docker's image to Heroku?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its asking for you to specify the app name

`heroku container:push web --app dockerlaravelwai`