# Can't release pushed docker image in heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-cli

I am pretty new to Heroku.

### Issue Description

After successfully pushing a docker image to Heroku Container Registry using JIB I am struggling to release it.

### What I did:

Pushed docker image using JIB:

```
[INFO] Built and pushed image as hamzablm/timesheet
[INFO] Executing tasks:
[INFO] [===========================   ] 88.9% complete
[INFO] > launching layer pushers
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  51.106 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-20T11:16:20Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

By now the image should be in the registry.
But when I want to release it:
`heroku container:release hamzablm/timesheet` It fails:

```
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help
```

I'm probably missing something simple here, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51695556/611497

Comment: This isn't my case because the image is already in the registry

Comment: Its the same error you need to specify your app name

Comment: It's weird, because from the Heroku CLI commands, if you check your section (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-container-release) it says that -a is a required option.. then, in the example is not specified. What if you try to manually specify the flag?

Comment: specifying -a option  doesn't work either: `▸    Couldn't find that app.`

Comment: The option is automatically inferred if you are into the directory of a create Heroku app or, if you used `heroku create <your-app-name>` or `heroku git:remote -a <your-app-name>` like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779162/error-missing-required-flag-a-app-app-app-to-run-command-against

Comment: Now after creating the app using `heroku create`. when I run `heroku container:release hamzablm/timesheet` it fails: `▸Expected response to be successful, got 404`

Comment: Uh, I'm not an expert but, did you check the constraints about the docker images? In particular, do you set `CMD` (look here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime)

Comment: Indeed it's automatically set by JIB. From the logs: ` Container entrypoint set to `[java, -cp, /app/resources:/app/classes:/app/libs/*, io.xhub.timesheet.TimeSheetApplication]`

Answer (score 3):

you are using the image name with the `heroku container:release` command, but you are supposed to use the name of the Heroku application.
This is normally what you need

```
docker push registry.heroku.com/appname/web
heroku container:release web -a appname
```

The application can be created via the Dashboard or the CLI

Comment: +1 This actually seems to work, it doesn't give me the usual error. But when I run `heroku container:release web -a timesheet` It says: `You do not have access to the app timesheet.` It's not working even after login to heroku using `heroku login` Am I missing something? help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you also `heroku container:login`? And check the app name is correct and matching the one created on Heroku

Comment: Do you tag the image?

Comment: Nope the connection was a success when running `heroku container:login` but `You do not have access to the app timesheet.` when running `heroku container:release web -a timesheet`

Comment: Ok, the workflow is the following:
- docker build -t myImage .
- docker tag myImage registry.heroku.com/myApp/web
- docker push registry.heroku.com/myApp/web
- heroku container:release web -a myApp

The tag specifies the process type (web) which is then needed by the release cmd

Answer (score 0):

So I encountered the same problem. However, I was working with a docker image that needed
to be tagged and pushed to the heroku registry through a pipeline in Travis CI. After this I saw it was not released yet. When trying to release the container it would fail and give the same error as you encountered. In the steps below I will explain my fix. Please note the $VARIABLE contain variables passed along in Travis CI.

## Step 1

I logged in to the Heroku with my Docker using the Heroku API key.

```
docker login --username _ --password=$HEROKU_API_KEY registry.heroku.com
```

## Step 2

I tagged my Docker image to the registry of Heroku.
Please note the following, I used the $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER as my process type.
This is a variable instantiated by Travis CI itself and does not have to be declared.
In the examples shown by Heroku they use the word "web" as example but you can specify it as you please.

```
docker tag $DOCKER_USER/$DOCKER_IMAGE:latest registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME/$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
```

## Step 3

I pushed the image to the Heroku registry.

```
docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME/$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
```

## Step 4

I released the container to Heroku by specifying the process type ($TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER) and the Heroku app name ($HEROKU_APP_NAME).

```
heroku container:release $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER --app $HEROKU_APP_NAME
```

I hope you already fixed it but this might give a better insight into why your command fails. It is missing a process type and the --app flag. In the example below I assumed hamzablm/timesheet was your $HEROKU_APP_NAME variable:

```
 heroku container:release $MISSING_PROCESS_TYPE --app hamzablm/timesheet
```

I hope this gives a better understanding.